# Upload files in public facing site

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have a public facing site built in ASP.Net. I want Admin/certain users to upload files to particular folder/database table. But currently I don't have any user facility nor any database tables, just some aspx pages hosted on internet.

Additionally if I use the admin user process, then, 
1. How to differentiate normal users from admin as I am not using any kind of registration process.

How can I achieve this. Please help.

Comment: Please provide code snippet that you have tried...

Comment: Nidhin, I am unable to think a logic yet that's why I need some logic to start. I think I am not clear with my question. I have edited my question. Please check and thanks for your prompt response.